# Using postman collection runner to POST request a json body

Tags: collections, postman, postman-collection-runner

I make a post request with a different json file every hour and I wondered if I can make this automated? I searched online and it looks like it can be done with collection runner or monitors?

URL: https://api.keepa.com/tracking?key=MY_API_KEY&type=add

Headers: Content-Type application/json

Body:

```
{"asin":"value",
"ttl": value,
"expireNotify": value,
"desiredPricesInMainCurrency": value,
"mainDomainId": value,
"updateInterval": value,
"metaData": value,
"thresholdValues":{"thresholdValue": value,"domain": value,"csvType": value,"isDrop": value},
"notifyIf": value,
"notificationType": value,
"individualNotificationInterval": value},
```

One json file has 1000 of these object. I have 100 json files.

Can someone give me some information about this please? Can I automate it with collection runner?

Comment: Have you posted this question before? Your question is not clear enough to let people help you. 1. what is your post request (url, header, body)? 2. 400 means there is something wrong with your request, please attach response to question.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many ways to schedule your Postman requests and one is creating a Postman monitor. Check [this](https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/monitoring-your-api/setting-up-monitor/) article to learn how to start. If you want to specialize your request you can use the Pre-request Script and Tests section.

**Sample Pre-request:**

[image: pre-request scripts]

**Sample Test:**

[image: tests]

**Monitor Console Log:**

[image: monitor console log]

**PS:** There is a quota for free Postman accounts. Total 1000 requests per month for Postman Monitoring. Buy a premium account or learn how to use Newman (Postman CLI) and how cron jobs work for making the same thing for free.